# How to use client side code in Visual studio ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax

I am a quite new to web development and I am trying to do some small form updates without causing a postback.  For example making a control visible when a drop down list is changed.

I have so far come across some features that achieve this like the RequiredFieldValidator inside an update panels.  However, these are specific to a single task.

What are my options to achieve these client side updates in Visual Studio?  At the moment I don't know any JavaScript, so I would prefer another solution if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know JQuery you should or at least any other Javascript library this will give you an edge and also pump up your resume. The learning curve of these JS frameworks is so short that you'll be creating awesome UI's in no time. I suggest that you take at least two hours to get to know JQuery you won't regret it.

**Here's a few great article on using ASP.NET with JQuery:**

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/using-jquery-with-asp-net.aspx

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1532-gridview-and-jquery-asp-net-tutorial.aspx

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-jQuery-ASP.NET.aspx

**Here are a few of the best tutorials on JQuery:**

http://www.ajaxline.com/best-jquery-tutorials-march-2010

Answer (score 1):

For display functionality like you have described, javascript really is the best solution.  Take a look at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), it makes writing javascript a lot easier, and you should be up and running with it in no time for tasks like your basic show/hide functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AJAX stands for 'Asynchronous Javascript and XML' so getting this behaviour without using Javascript is going to land you in a bit of a pickle.

Update Panels *do* work and are very easy, but they're also very slow in comparison as even if you only see the contents of your panel update, the entire ASP page has to be executed.

I'd urge you to take a deep breath and head over to JQuery.Com and practise the tutorials there. Javascript is easier then you think and JQuery takes a lot of the hardships of cross-browser compatibility out of the picture, leaving you to focus on the real tasks.

Good Luck!